# Why http live streaming done not support SubRip (.srt) subtitles?

Tags: http-live-streaming, srt

I have meet some time issues about http live streaming for supporting srt subtitles. But after researching, I hardly can find the practices about HLS supporting srt. So why http live streaming not support SubRip (.srt) subtitles? and what kind of problem will be if I want to implement to support srt for HLS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Live Streaming supports only **Web Video Text Tracks (WebVTT)** subtitles. Converting your .srt to the supported format should be pretty easy.

**Why?** Because WebVTT (Web Video Text Tracks) is a W3C standard for use with HTML5